# SearchExercises.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: bodyPartsData is not iterable at fetchExercisesData

Tags: reactjs

Here is code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
      const bodyPartsData = await fetchData('https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList', exerciseOptions);

      setBodyParts(['all', ...bodyPartsData]);
    };

    fetchExercisesData();
  }, []);
```

And here is the fetchData code from the other component

```
export const fetchData = async (url, options) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = response.json();

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to await till response.json() to resolve

```
export const fetchData = async (url, options) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: holy! I didn't see that. thanks!!!!